# Left-align chart title in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

How can I left-align the chart title in a `plot_ly` object (as created from `ggplotly`)?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("My Title") + 
  # Not necessary by default:
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.0))

p

ggplotly(p)
```

Output of `p` (intended title alignment):

[image]

`ggplotly(p)` (title alignment not preserved):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do

```
ggplotly(p) %>%
  add_annotations(
    yref="paper", 
    xref="paper", 
    y=1.15, 
    x=0, 
    text="My Title", 
    showarrow=F, 
    font=list(size=17)
  ) %>% 
  layout(title=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 13):

`plot_ly` has [added](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/882) this functionality. Now you can call:

```r
ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(
    title = list(
      xanchor = "right"
    )
  )
```

or

```r
ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(
    title = list(
      x = 0.1
    )
  )
```

where `x` is the normalized position, with `x=0` positioning all the way to the left and `x=1` positioning all the way to the right.