# How do you center the title in a R Plotly pie chart?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am working with Plotly using R and am having trouble centering the title over the pie chart.  The title looks like it is a little off to the right. Is there a way to do this and move it left or closer to the middle of the pie chart?

This is the code:

```
label_names = c('Feeds','All Others') 
numbers = c(first_reported, not_first_reported)

pie_colors <- c('rgba(173,216,230,1)', 'rgba(0,0,139,1)')
plot_ly(labels=label_names, values=numbers, type='pie', 
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        marker = list(colors=pie_colors)) %>%
  layout(title = 'Portion of Feeds')
```

What the chart looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks similar to this question, [Left-align chart title in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712678/left-align-chart-title-in-plotly),
just slightly modifying the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712678/left-align-chart-title-in-plotly#answer-44716028) here, should work for this too.

```
plot_ly(labels=label_names, values=numbers, type='pie', 
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        marker = list(colors=pie_colors)) %>%
  add_annotations(
    y=1.05, 
    x=0.5, 
    text="Portion of Feeds", 
    showarrow=F,
    font=list(size=15)
  )
```

source: